# How to make Table Footer Collapse and Expand in DataTable Responsive?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I tried to have my `dataTable` display friendly on mobile device; for this purpose I extended my `dataTable` with `responsive` extension. Then it looks pretty good that it auto collapse column to fit the screen width.

#### Problem:

My Table consists mostly of number that is it is necessary to show total number at the footer of the table.

At this point, `dataTable` with `responsive` extension is a bit frustrated that it does not treat data in footer, the total number, collapsible and expansible as the table body.

Therefore, the total number columns in table footer are missing when viewing on mobile devices.

```js
$('table').DataTable();
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 140%;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

table caption {
  padding: .5em 0;
}

table.dataTable th,
table.dataTable td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 140px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.4/css/dataTables.responsive.css'>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Languages</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Median Age</th>
            <th>Area (Km²)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Argentina</td>
            <td>Spanish (official), English, Italian, German, French</td>
            <td>41,803,125</td>
            <td>31.3</td>
            <td>2,780,387</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Australia</td>
            <td>English 79%, native and other languages</td>
            <td>23,630,169</td>
            <td>37.3</td>
            <td>7,739,983</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Greece</td>
            <td>Greek 99% (official), English, French</td>
            <td>11,128,404</td>
            <td>43.2</td>
            <td>131,956</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Luxembourg</td>
            <td>Luxermbourgish (national) French, German (both administrative)</td>
            <td>536,761</td>
            <td>39.1</td>
            <td>2,586</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russia</td>
            <td>Russian, others</td>
            <td>142,467,651</td>
            <td>38.4</td>
            <td>17,076,310</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>Swedish, small Sami- and Finnish-speaking minorities</td>
            <td>9,631,261</td>
            <td>41.1</td>
            <td>449,954</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>229197371</th>
            <th>230.4</th>
            <th>28181176</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.4/js/dataTables.responsive.js'></script>
```

#### Purpose

I'm not quit sure this behavior of dataTable is possible or not **to have table footer columns be collapsible and expansible like a table body**. I tried to google around this topic, but not help address this problem.

**Note:** there are some alternatives over `dataTable` as listed in article [Responsive Data Tables: A Comprehensive List of Solutions](https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-data-tables-comprehensive-list-solutions/) which does differently for viewing table on small device, yet my project work is solely used `dataTable`. Thanks.

Comment: this is not possible from databale api. you have to use JS to do it . 
you can add a button in tfoot, and create a js function on click. and add another row in tfoot, and make it hide or show on button click

Comment: @AhmedSunny, How can I achieve that? I don't know much about dataTable api js related. Thanks.